# CMS - Restrict list view from loading relations causing slow render

Tags: strapi

I am currently using Strapi v3.0.0-beta.17.5 so i do admit i'm not up to date. However, i currently have an issue where loading data in the CMS seems to have a delay even though the data doesn't have many records.

I have a table called Events which does have a relation field. This relation field can have up to around 10,000 records.

There are currently 8 events but i'm finding that when i go to list them in the CMS, it takes around 3 or 4 seconds to populate the list.

My assumption is that this is because it's loading the relations in the background.

Is there a way to not include the relations? This would be good to know for the api side of things too as sometimes i just want the main Event object data and not the relations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating the content - I share with you a GitHub issue about this topic - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4775